# C - Importing Python Module

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-import

I'm using the `<Python.h>` library, this is the first time that I use it and I did some research. Finally I found what is my problem exactly but don't really know how to fix it.

I want to parse url with Beautifulsoup, the Python code works perfectly but when I want to use `PyImport_ImportModule(parser)` to import my file (named parser.py) but it doesn't rencogniez the bs4 module from my import `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Here is the part of my C program :

```
    PyObject *return, *module, *function, *args;

    Py_Initialize();

    PySys_SetPath(".");
    module = PyImport_ImportModule("parser");

    if(module == NULL){
        PyErr_Print();
        exit(1);
    }
    fonction = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "link_list");
```

Where `link_list` is my Python function who only takes a string. So I know that I have to import bs4 too with `PyImport` but nothing work correctly and I still have this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./parser.py", line 2, in 
>       from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>   ImportError: No module named bs4

I insist my parser.py works perfectly with `Python2.7` and when I'm compiling my C program I use `gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 pars.c -lpython2.7 -o pars -Wall` but if you need to see how I'm using it here's my Python program :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


def link_list(urlString):
    siteFile = urllib2.urlopen(urlString)
    siteHTML = siteFile.read()
    siteFile.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(siteHTML, "html.parser")
    liste = []
    for links in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(links.get('href'))
        liste.append(links.get('href'))
    return liste
```

### **Update : Fixed !**

If you encounter a problem when you try to import any module (in my case urllib2) and you can see this error : `Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder`this mean you're certainly a mac user who installed Python with homebrew. In my case I did this :

```
cp /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

It depending of the version of Python you use. If you don't have this use `sudo find / -name _io.so` and look for the `/System` path to _io.so and the `/usr/local/Cellar/python/` with the most recent version of python and use the `cp`command with them.

Comment: Can you try using PyRun_SimpleString("import parser")? Also make sure the python script is in the same path where your C source code is and you have `__init__.py` in the directory. I presume you could able to import 'parser' successfully on python shell (this is for testing only)

Comment: I did some more research and try `PyRun_SimpleString("from bs4 import BeautifulSoup\n")` now bs4 is imported but doesn't recognize urllib2 now. And it doesn't work with `PyRun_SimpleString`
`__init__.py`what is it and where can I find it ?

Comment: Ok I have an empty `__init__.py` in my directory, I can import parser in my python shell but it doesn't work when I do it with `PyRun_SimpleString` it telling me the same thing, there's no bs4 module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked for me, please try this:

```
    /* 1st: Import the module */
    PyObject* ModuleString = PyString_FromString((char*) "parser");
    if (!ModuleString) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Error formating python script\n");
    }

    PyObject* Module = PyImport_Import(ModuleString);
    if (!Module) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Error importing python script\n");
    }

    /* 2nd: Getting reference to the function */
    PyObject* Function = PyObject_GetAttrString(Module, (char*)"link_list");
    if (!Function) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Error getting link_list()\n");
    }
```

**Update:**

I have attached the complete process, compiled on MacOS.

```
[milinddeore@MDEORE-M-P028: ~/temp ] ls
__init__.py pars.c      parser.py
[milinddeore@MDEORE-M-P028: ~/temp ] vim pars.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

int main() {
  Py_Initialize();

  /* This is to add the path in the code */
  PyObject *sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
  PyObject *path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
  PyList_Append(path, PyString_FromString("."));

  /* 1st: Import the module */
    PyObject* ModuleString = PyString_FromString((char*) "parser");
    if (!ModuleString) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Error formating python script\n");
    }

    PyObject* Module = PyImport_Import(ModuleString);
    if (!Module) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Error importing python script\n");
    }

    /* 2nd: Getting reference to the function */
    PyObject* Function = PyObject_GetAttrString(Module, (char*)"link_list");
    if (!Function) {
        PyErr_Print();
        printf("Pass valid argument to link_list()\n");
    }

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
[milinddeore@MDEORE-M-P028: ~/temp ] vim parser.py
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


def link_list(urlString):
    siteFile = urllib2.urlopen(urlString)
    siteHTML = siteFile.read()
    siteFile.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(siteHTML, "html.parser")
    liste = []
    for links in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(links.get('href'))
        liste.append(links.get('href'))
    return liste
[milinddeore@MDEORE-M-P028: ~/temp ] gcc -I/usr/include/python2.7 pars.c -lpython2.7 -o pars -Wall
[milinddeore@MDEORE-M-P028: ~/temp ] ls
__init__.py pars        pars.c      parser.py
[milinddeore@MDEORE-M-P028: ~/temp ] ./pars
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'link_list'
Pass valid argument to link_list()     ===> This is because i have not passed the required argument to the function.
```

Let me know if you need any other details. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this and got the error from the import :
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parser.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
Error importing python script
[1]    72505 segmentation fault  ./pars`

Comment: Please find the snippet of the process that i followed. Hope this helps?

Comment: Well I made a completely new file with your code and it works like you. Thank you, but I just don't understand where is the problem with the function. As soon as I fix this I will add the rest of my program and test it. If I have some problem I will post it here.

Comment: You're not using the same parser... it doesn't use the working directory. So you need to use `PySys_SetPath(".")` to use the correct directory. So it doesn't work.

Comment: Why you need to set the path explicitly in the code, when you could able to run python outside pars.c program. Did you set PYTHONPATH or PATH while installing python? Can you run `whereis python2.7`. When you do `PySys_SetPath(".")` you actually clear python path to `"."` as it updates `sys.path`. To test this run Py_GetPath() before and after PySys_SetPath(). Anyway if you still want to set the path in the C code please look at the edited code.

Comment: I wanted to set the path because when I changed the file name of `parser.py`to `html_parser.py`it doesn't recognized it. He used an another file in the default path named `parser.py`and when I changed all with `html_parser.py`it didn't find the file to import. You can try it, just change the Python file name and eventually it wont work anymore. This is my fault by using a such file name...

Comment: I finally found... it's a problem with homebrew and _io.so, I don't know why it didn't found the symbole and all I got to do was cp the one in my System Framwork to the homebrew directory. Thanks a lot, if you didn't give me this program I wouldn't find this.

Comment: Cheers, happy coding :)

Comment: I will edit my post to help anybody encountering the same issue.